# Trigonometry Calculation

Tags: trigonometry

How does one solve: $ \frac 1 2=\cos \theta $
I know the solutions are $300^\circ$ degrees and $60^\circ$; however, my knowledge of theory here is lacking.

I suppose it should go something like: $$X_1 = \alpha+360^\circ k$$ $$X_2 = -\alpha+360^\circ k$$

However, what determines the value of $k$? Can any $k$ be assigned ($k\in \Bbb N$, of course)?

In this case after $k=1$ solutions seem to repeat themselves.

Comment: Your analysis is fine. If you can find all the solutions in some interval of length $360^\circ$, such as the interval $(0^\circ, 360^\circ]$, or $(-180^\circ,180^\circ]$, then you can get all solutions by adding $k\cdot 360^\circ$, where $k$ ranges over all integers, positive, negative, or $0$.

Comment: sin, cos functions is a periodic function that repeats the same form by 360-degree cycle. Your thought is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in fact, $k$ can be any $k \in \mathbb Z$, and in this case, $\alpha = 60^\circ$.
$$\cos \theta = \frac 12 \implies \theta = \pm 60^\circ + 360^\circ k$$

Answer (score 1):

if $\cos \theta=\cos\alpha$, then $\theta=2n\pi\pm\alpha$, where $n \in \mathbb Z$

In your case $\cos\theta=\cos \frac{\pi}{3}$ ,therefore,

$\theta=2n\pi\pm\frac{\pi}{3}$